# How to georeference two pictures that do not have crs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I would like to take aerial pictures of my research plots an caculate NDVI and NDWI. How do I do that in QGIS?

Comment: When you say aerial pictures, are they orthorectified? Are your images multi-spectral or just plane RGB? Georeferencing is one thing, but not having the IR band is another. You may be better off sourcing imagery with the necessary band information that is already georeferenced.

Comment: Answering Chris (for some reason I cant comment on your post directly):
my research plots are relatively small (1-2 ha). I plan to take aerial photoes using digital cameras mounted on a Quadcopter. I have one Camera in IR and a second in RGB.

Comment: Unless you've planned for it in your process, those images won't be orthorectified and will contain some perspective distortion. Since you're using two cameras (same time?) there will be some offset in perspective and/or exact photo locations, so you'll also have to do some co-registration work or georeference them separately to the same control points. Zimmi's answer, while it could use some expanding, links to one georeferencing tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

See [Georeferencing Topo Sheets and Scanned Maps](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html).